Why does Make automatically execute a cc command?
I'm trying to learn how to use Make! So I have this simple Makefile,
all: main other

main: main.c other.o
    gcc main.c -o main
    echo "Compiled main.exe"

other: other.o

other.c:
    touch $@
    echo "int main(){return 0;}" > $@
    echo "Created other.c"

other.o: other.c
    gcc other.c -o other.o
    echo "Compiled other.o"

clean:
    rm -f main.exe other.o other.c

where everything executes as expected except at the end where a cc compile command is executed. Here is the output (I added the arrow),
> make all  
touch other.c
echo "int main(){return 0;}" > other.c
echo "Created other.c"
Created other.c
gcc other.c -o other.o
echo "Compiled other.o"
Compiled other.o
gcc main.c -o main
echo "Compiled main.exe"
Compiled main.exe
cc   other.o   -o other     <---
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: other.o: in functio
n `mainCRTStartup':
/c/S/B/src/msys2-runtime/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:20: multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
; /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../crt0.o:/c/S/B/src/msys2-runtime/winsup/cygw
in/crt0.c:20: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: other.o: in functio
n `mainCRTStartup':
/c/S/B/src/msys2-runtime/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c:20: multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStart
up'; /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../crt0.o:/c/S/B/src/msys2-runtime/winsup/c
ygwin/crt0.c:20: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: other.o:cygming-crt
beg:(.text+0x50): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'; /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-m
sys/13.2.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbeg:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: other.o:cygming-crt
beg:(.text+0x70): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'; /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc
-msys/13.2.0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbeg:(.text+0x20): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: other.o:cygming-crt
beg:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'; /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/13.2.
0/crtbegin.o:cygming-crtbeg:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: other] Error 1

Where the "<---" points to is the line in question. Why is this getting executed?

OT: You don't need the touch command. If the file doesn't exist then the redirection will create it.

This Makefile doesn't really make sense to me. You have dependencies that aren't used (other.o for main) and your main target (seemingly, given the message and clean target) produces main.exe instead of main.

The problem is this dependency:  other: other.o  There is no associated rule after this dependency, so it falls back on a default rule.  Note that it isn't compiling.  It's just using cc to link other.  If you want to produce other in some other way, then you should add an explicit rule to make it, rather than using a default rule as you are now.

@TomKarzes am I not making other.o? I assumed if other: other.o is executed then it looks for the other.o rule which is in place.

@ThomasJager I understand it appears random but it's just a file used for practive and there's no real need to look into it too much

@verpas The dependency other: other.o makes other.  Look at the left side of the dependency.  It's other, not other.o.  So it first checks if other.o is current, and if not, invokes the rule to make it.  It then excutes the default rule to make other, since you neglected to provide an explicit rule.  It's pretty simple.  You need to decide what you want.  Do you want to make other?  Of not, then just delete that line.  If you do, then tell it how to make it.  This shouldn't be confusing.

The problem is that the default program to build and link programs is cc. And with the rule other: other.o you tell make to build the executable other from the object file other.o which it will then do using the default linker.
And the errors are because gcc other.c -o other.o builds an executable program file named other.o. To build an object file you need to use the -c option.
The simple solution to all your problems, really, is to set the CC and LD variables, and rely on implicit rules to build your code.
Such a Makefile could look something like this:
# Explicitly use gcc as the compiler and linker
CC = gcc
LD = gcc

# The "default" target, because the first target in the makefile
# is what make will use when no target is specified
default: main other

# Build the main executable program from the main.c source
main: main.c

# Build the other executable program from the other.c source
other: other.c

# Create the other.c source file
other.c:
    echo "int main(){return 0;}" > $@

# The clean target isn't for creating a "clean" file, it's phony, fake
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f main other other.c

[Please note that you need to convert the indentation to tabs]


Why does Make automatically execute a cc command?

These are implicit rules.
Assuming you're using GNU Make, have a read through https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html , which states

Linking a single object file
n is made automatically from n.o by running the C compiler to
link the program. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o
$(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’.


(Replace n by other for your case.)
To understand the mentioned variables such as CC, see also the section on implicit variables. This is why you're seeing cc on that line:

CC
Program for compiling C programs; default ‘cc’.

since the CC variable is used for the linking part.

I will study those links! Thank you!

So I posted this question before I knew about .PHONY, and since the reason for the error is an implicity rule, setting the rule to .PHONY: other, removes the error because it no longer tries to build other. I hope this helps someone!
